# wp_ajax_action, wp_ajax_nopriv_action not working

Tags: ajax

I'm using jquery autocomplete.

Here is my code..

admin-ajax.php

```
function my_search_one() { die($_GET['term']);

        //..sample data..

   }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_search', 'my_search_one' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_search', 'my_search_two' );
```

jquery autocomplete code

```
(function( $ ) {
$(function() {
    var url = MyAutocomplete.url + "?action=my_search";
    $( "#spotlight_spotlight_make_user_also_as_spotlight" ).autocomplete({
        source: url,
        delay: 500,
        minLength: 3
    }); 
});

})( jQuery );
```

Everything is working fine except following hooks "**wp_ajax_my_search**" & "**wp_ajax_nopriv_my_search**", my_search_one() function not being fired. please, let me know the reason. I hope, this code could be enough. I will place more code, if required. but please, help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you look the HTTP request at the AJAX URL with the Network Monitor of your browser ?

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: using firebug to test, where i am able to see passed-parameters but no response from server. Ajax request is going to admin-ajax.php but function my_search_one() not firing. I think, there is issue in hooks. please, let me know.

Comment: Works when I try it. Where is your code?